# Readfile() occasionally returns 998 / ERROR_NOACCESS

Tags: windows, winapi, buffer, readfile

I am trying to implement fast IO under Windows, and working my way up to Overlapped IO.  In my research, Unbuffered IO requires page aligned buffers. Ive attempted to implement this in my code below. However, I occasionally have Readfiles last error report no access (error 998, ERROR_NOACCESS) - prior to completing the read, and after a few reads of a page aligned buffer. Sometimes 16. Sometimes 4, etc.

I cant for the life of me figure out why i am occasionally throwing an error. Any insight would be helpful.

```
ci::BufferRef CinderSequenceRendererApp::CreateFileLoadWinNoBufferSequential(fs::path path) {
HANDLE file = CreateFile(path.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING | FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, 0);

if (file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    console() << "Could not open file for reading" << std::endl;
}

ci::BufferRef latestAvailableBufferRef = nullptr;

LARGE_INTEGER nLargeInteger = { 0 };

GetFileSizeEx(file, &nLargeInteger);

// how many reads do we need to fill our buffer with a buffer size of x and a read size of y
// Our buffer needs to hold 'n' sector sizes that wil fit the size of the file

SYSTEM_INFO si;
GetSystemInfo(&si);
long readAmount = si.dwPageSize;

int numReads = 0;
ULONG bufferSize = 0;

// calculate sector aligned buffer size that holds our file size
while (bufferSize < nLargeInteger.QuadPart)
{
    numReads++;
    bufferSize = (numReads) * readAmount;
}

// need one page extra for null if we need it
latestAvailableBufferRef = ci::Buffer::create(bufferSize + readAmount);

if (latestAvailableBufferRef != nullptr)
{
    DWORD outputBytes = 1;

    // output bytes = 0 when OEF
    void* address = latestAvailableBufferRef->getData();
    DWORD bytesRead = 0;
    while (outputBytes != 0)
    {
        bool result = ReadFile(file, address, readAmount, &outputBytes, 0);
        if (!result )//&& (outputBytes == 0))
        {
            getLastReadError();
        }

        address = (void*)((long)address + readAmount);
        bytesRead += outputBytes;

    }
}

CloseHandle(file);  

// resize our buffer to expected file size?
latestAvailableBufferRef->resize(nLargeInteger.QuadPart);

return latestAvailableBufferRef;
}
```

Comment: Casting an address to `long` will usually break in a 64 bit build.

Comment: This was totally it. I caught it right after I posted. Derp. Thanks you.

Comment: Also, your code is detecting API errors but is not reacting to them.  If `CreateFile()` fails to open the file, you are still moving ahead and working with the invalid file handle.  If `GetFileSizeEx()` fails, you are still moving ahead and using the invalid file size. If `ReadFile()` fails, you are still moving ahead and processing the unread data. If an error happens, STOP WHAT YOU ARE DOING, close the file, and process the error as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast to long long - I was truncating my pointer address. Duh. Thanks to @jonathan-potter